# Create an all-day event using Google Calendar API

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

Iam working with C# and the Google Calendar API classes "CalendarService" and "Event".
I want to upload an event to Google Calendar without any date (all-day).
If i don't set the Event.End property, I get an exception.

How can I set my event as an all-day event ?

I've searched for a long time, without any solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a new time with `AllDay` set to true:

```
var entry = new EventEntry(title, description, "");
var time = new When();
time.StartTime = start;
time.AllDay = true;

entry.Times.Add(time);
```

Comment: You can add EndTime and still have AllDay set to true. That way you can add an event for multiple days.

Answer (score 2):

Isn´t the marked answer Java???

He asked about c#.

```
Event newEvent = new Event()
        {

            Summary = "5ummary",
            Location = "location avenue",
            Description = "description",
            Start = new EventDateTime()
            {
                Date = "2015-08-07",

            },
            End = new EventDateTime()
            {
                Date = "2015-08-07",

            },

        };
```

Comment: I find that using this format I get a 400 error of Too Short, still investigating.